# How can you count vowels in string in f#

Tags: string, f#

How do you do count vowels in string in f# ?

```
let inputText = "sdhkjhsakdnadwqerdsdasefds"
let vowels = ["a";"e";"i";"o";"u"]
let count inputText = Seq.filter ((=) vowels) >> Seq.length
printfn "%A" count
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

Comment: Do you use FSI (F# interactive)? You can run code in FSI with Alt-Enter in Visual Studio or VS Code and solve problems like this in smaller pieces. It should help you to learn much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let inputText = "sdhkjhsakdnadwqerdsdasefds"
let vowels = ['a';'e';'i';'o';'u']
let isVowel =
    fun c -> vowels |> List.contains c

let count =
    String.filter isVowel
    >> String.length

printfn "%A" (count inputText)
```

I changed your list of vowels to a list of chars instead of strings. You have to actually use the `inputText` argument in your function. You also have to convert the string to an array of chars before filtering it. And then you have to give your `inputText` as an argument to your function. The function argument `inputText` and the variable `inputText` have nothing in common except the name.

EDIT: Factored out the isVowel function, and removed the inputText argument from count, instead using your preferred method with `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let proj x =
    if Array.contains x [| 'a';'e';'i';'o';'u' |] then 1
    else 0

let count (text: string) =
    text.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.sumBy proj
```